# Java: Using String.indexOf() to check for the apostrophe character

Tags: java

I am trying to parse a string and I need to use substring to do it. The string contains the apostrophe characters. My question is, how do I use temp to get String.indexOf to get the index of the apostrophe character?

```
//temp variable currently contains the string 'hello' including the apostrophe character
String finalWord = temp.substring(temp.indexOf('''), temp.indexOf('.'));
```

Comment: What are you *really* trying to do? I'm sure you don't actually care where the apostrophe is. Are you trying to get all characters between apostrophe, or remove apostrophes, or what?

Comment: I am <i>really</i> seriously trying to find a way to store every word that has apostrophe's around it, in its own variable, without the apostrophes.

Comment: See my answer for a more direct approach

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your variable name is wrong(`final` is a reserved word) and you should use escape character:

```
String finalword = temp.substring(temp.indexOf('\''), temp.indexOf('.'));
```

Comment: @MHZ Please copy-paste your exact code into your question so we can see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your last comment, which declares what you're *actually* trying to do...

There is a simple one-line solution for extracting every apostrophe-quoted string from input:

```
String[] quotedStrings = input.replaceAll("^.*?'|'[^']*$", "").split("'.*?('|$)");
```

Here's some test code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "xxx'foo'xxx'bar'xxx'baz'xxx";
    String[] quotedStrings = input.replaceAll("^.*?'|'[^']*$", "").split("'.*?('|$)");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(quotedStrings));
}
```

Output:

```
[foo, bar, baz]
```